# Using asynctask for network connection

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, android-asynctask

I am trying to incorporate asynctask into my code as I get a force close at the minute due to `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

I have gone through a few tutorials but I still cannot get my head around it. Every time I try it out, I just get errors all over the place.

Tutorials I looked at:

1. [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html][1]
2. [https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/][2]

Basically what the code is doing is:

1. Taking an IP Address from an intent.
2. Connecting to the IP with port 32
3. Then send a command, wait for response and the send another command.
4. After the 2 commands our sent I should get a response of "SNX_COM>"
5. Once the connection is established, I want the connection to stay open to send specific commands on button click.

^^That's basically what my code should achieve ^^

```
package com.smarte.smartipcontrol;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class IPControl extends Activity {

private Socket socket;
private String serverIpAddress = "com.smarte.smartipcontrol.ACTU_IP";
private static final int REDIRECTED_SERVERPORT = 32;
public PrintWriter out;
public BufferedReader in;
public String data;
public Object pd;



public void getModel(View view) {
    try {
        out.println("[m\r\n");
        //System.out.print("root\r\n");
        while(!in.ready());
        String textStatus = readBuffer();

    } catch(IOException e) {}
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   setContentView(R.layout.act_ipcontrol);


   try{   

    new AsyncAction().execute();

   }catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

   }



private class AsyncAction extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
   protected String doInBackground(String... args) { 
   try {
 InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
 socket = new Socket(serverAddr, REDIRECTED_SERVERPORT);
} catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
 e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
 e1.printStackTrace();
}
try {
 out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true); in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
 while (! in .ready());
 readBuffer();
 out.println("root\r\n");
 //System.out.print("root\r\n");
 while (! in .ready());
 readBuffer();
 out.println("root\r\n");
 //System.out.print("root\r\n");
 while (! in .ready());
 String msg = "";

while ( in .ready()) {
 msg = msg + (char) in .read();
}
} catch (IOException e) {}

       return null;//returns what you want to pass to the onPostExecute()
   }

   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

   //results the data returned from doInbackground

       IPControl.this.data = result;



       }
   }


private String readBuffer() throws IOException {
    String msg = "";

    while(in.ready()) {
        msg = msg + (char)in.read();
    }
    //System.out.print(msg);
    if(msg.indexOf("SNX_COM> ") != -1) return msg.substring(0, msg.indexOf("SNX_COM> "));
    else return msg;
}

}
```

LogCat

```
12-03 15:39:56.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2697): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
12-03 15:39:56.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2697): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-03 15:39:56.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2697):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
12-03 15:39:56.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2697):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
12-03 15:39:56.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2697):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
12-03 15:39:56.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2697):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
12-03 15:39:56.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2697):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-03 15:39:56.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2697):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-03 15:39:56.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2697):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-03 15:39:56.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2697):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-03 15:39:56.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2697): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-03 15:39:56.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2697):     at com.smarte.smartipcontrol.IPControl$AsyncAction.doInBackground(IPControl.java:71)
12-03 15:39:56.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2697):     at com.smarte.smartipcontrol.IPControl$AsyncAction.doInBackground(IPControl.java:1)
12-03 15:39:56.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2697):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-03 15:39:56.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2697):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-03 15:39:56.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2697):     ... 4 more
```

Comment: hi you can try <a href="http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html">this</a>

Comment: Show some code where you actually use AsyncTask

Comment: I have please see updated code and LogCat, still getting issues, I am starting to lose my marbles -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move your `createConnection();` to `doInBackground()` of your asynctask which you have to add as inner class or separate class of your project
For example :

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
 protected Void doInBackground(Param[]...) {
     createConnection();
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate() {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute() {


 }
```

}

This is from first link you provided I just changed it a little bit. Make sure you return something from method createConnection() so that you know that asynctask has finished successfully or not and change DownloadFilesTask accordingly so that `doInBackground()` and `onPostExecute()` returns the same type

Comment: What is on line 71 ? Stupid question - did you put <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />  in manifest

Comment: Hi thanks for your responses, I have now fixed the above problem but now have a new problem -_-

Answer (score 1):

> Once the connection is established, I want the connection to stay open to send specific commands on button click.

You might have to make a new thread when you want to send commands to the server:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View arg0)
    {
      new Thread()
      {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
          methods.sendCommandToServer();
        } 
      }.start(); 
     } 
  });
```